# If I'm using PayPal on my web store, do I need to worry about user's credit card?

Tags: paypal, payment, opayo

I'm trying to find an answer of a general question.

I'm developing a webstore using Paypal (Express checkout) and Sagepay.
So, if in the report paypal confirms that the payment is actually done, e.g.:

> PAYMENTINFO_0_ACK = Success

Do I need to worry if the user's card is valid, stolen, 3Dsecurity, etc., or PayPal takes care of all this?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because only PayPal can give an authoritative answer and the question is not directly related to a coding problem.

Comment: If you are using Sage Pay to integrate Pay Pal, all your response fields will be in the SP format - you won't get PAYMENTINFO_0_ACK = Success, you'll get Status=OK StatusDetail=The authorisation was successful.

Comment: I'm using both operators separately. SagePay sends some messages to inform you that for example the user has different billing address, so it may be fraud. Or that the user failed on 3D security check.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially yes. Although I'm not exactly sure about that specific attribute you have given an example of.

If you send the item to the address given on the PayPal transaction and the transaction is not under review or pending, then you have what they call 'seller protection'.

This protects against hacked accounts or stolen card details etc.

It's a little difficult to find out on the PayPal website. https://www.paypal.com/uk/webapps/mpp/paypal-safety-and-security

Edit: If in doubt, contact PayPal. https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/helpcenter/helphub/home/

Although it is sometimes very difficult to get providers like this to admit liability, it's a little more black and white with PayPal.